# PHP. How to find the previous page?

Tags: php

I would like to know what page redirected to the current page on my system.

For example. If the system stopped in the page *current.php*.
How to know what page called *current.php*?

Is there a function to perform this?

Comment: http is a [stateless protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can contain the URL of the page the user agent was previously on, but it can be spoofed or empty.

Comment: Strange, the field 'HTTP_REFERER' doesn't exist on my _SERVER variable. But var_dumping =) _SERVER solved the problem to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a reliable way of doing that.

If you're expecting the redirecting page to be on your server, you can set a `$_SESSION` variable to the current page on every page you visit, that way, you can check for it on the next page (before resetting it of course).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are better solutions, but you could use a hidden field inside a form to transfer this information between pages inside your system, or use GET vars in your URL.
Rhis way you can keep track of certain states during page changes, that u are interested in.
But u would also need to update every page to handle the additional variables.